# Is this diagram correct for difference between 2N and N2

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, atoms, molecules, mole

[image]

There is 1 $\ce{N2}$ molecule formed with 2 atoms of nitrogen.
2N is 2 separate nitrogen atoms which have not formed any bond.Reasons could be that they didn’t get enough energy to form bond so they are present separately.

I want to confirm is this right ?

Comment: So, the question is what's the difference between an atom and a diatomic molecule?

Comment: Well, that is pretty muc the difference between two atoms and a molecule. But you don't need energy to form a bond. Bond formation *releases* energy.

Comment: It is also 2N means 2 molecules of nitrogen with 1 atom right @orthocresol

Comment: N2 is 1 molecule with 1 atom.

Comment: N2 is one molecule with *two* atoms. There’s no such thing as a molecule with one atom, by definition: molecules are things that have more than one atom.

Comment: @user277768 Two hints for future reference. #1) It is fine to use the extended formatting on ChemSE, especially mathjax and mhchem (https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/), in questions, answers, comments.  But because they are something special some programs don't understand well enough for a correct display, don't use them in the title of a question.  #2 If you add a photo, consider a) to crop the important / to trimm off parts which are not relevant to the question with an editor like [irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/) or [pinta](https://www.pinta-project.com/). And b) scale it down.

Comment: @orthocresol Jus on question.It is written in my textbook that 2N means two nascent nitrogen.What does that mean then sir?

Comment: @orthocresol please help sir

Answer (score 1):

1. One $\ce{N2}$ molecule formed:

   What you have drawn here is (as I have understood) Lewis dot diagram of the $\ce{N2}$ molecule. The correct way of drawing the molecule is as in 1)
2. Two separate N atoms which have not yet formed any bond:

   With the concept of Lewis dot structure formula the Nitrogen atoms are represented as in 2)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for correcting my diagram but what about the question I wrote you think

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation. Your Assumption is
2N is two nitrogen atoms progressing their way to make a bond to become N2.
2N doesn’t mean separate N atoms, because we are in the process of making N2.My Answer:
If you are saying as above, then you mean a quasi or semi bond between two N atoms – which is similar to transition state preceding to the product formation as in reaction mechanisms.

Comment: The 2 in 2N as per universal convention means stoichiometric coefficient, and 2 in N2, means atomicity of a molecule.
So when we mention 2N we never mean a molecule or a semi molecule, but two separate atoms instead of writing N N.
As I have understood even if that 2N quasi molecule exists, that has not been trapped yet to get a structure.

Hence in my  opinion 2N is two separate N atoms, which could only be depicted as per the rules of Lewis Structure.

Comment: Ok.And N2 is a 1 molecule of two atoms.Can’t we say 2N as 2 molecules ?

Comment: More than one atom BONDS together to form a molecule. More than one atom not yet bonded by transfer or sharing of electrons simply means atoms not molecules.This is the case with 2N atoms. There is no such transfer or sharing of electrons when we write 2N. Hence they are atoms.